# Teach + Uncommon Object

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, expressions, vocabulary

After I asked a question on Psychology and Neuroscience SE, some confusion arose over my use of the phrase 'to teach a disorder'

I was told that 'to teach a disorder' is a poor choice of words when trying to convey that ...

> I am not asking whether people can be taught but whether the disorder itself can be taught to people previously not suffering from the disorder or exacerbated in those already suffering.

Since a disagreement arose, I was deferred to this website to ask whether it is appropriate or not.

[Here are the various definitions of the entry teach in Lexico powered by Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/teach)  I hope through the context to make it clear that I mean the definition:

> 2 [with object and clause] Cause (someone) to learn something by example or experience.

What is wrong with 'teaching children a disorder' ? I.e., why isn't it proper English and/or understandable?

Comment: Not everything that's learned is taught or can be taught.  In your example, note that the speaker asks if parenting, schooling and/or close social rings could cause children to learn developmental disorders rather than saying they "teach" them.  It's clear that "teach" isn't being used because the speaker is indicating that the learning is a consequence of those things and not actually taught by those things.

Comment: That said, if a disorder could be learned in a way that someone teaching could lead someone else to acquire that disorder, then we would employ the verb "to have" (i.e., "What is wrong with teaching children to have a disorder?").

Comment: @Benjamin I agree. That sounds a whole lot better and is I believe the phrasing the OP is after. Consider adding that as an answer. 

Comment: @BenjaminHarman When I wrote teach a disorder. I meant cause young children to learn or understand that disorder by example or experience.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Are you sure you mean "to understand"? You made it very clear (I thought) in the (now removed after relevant edits) comments on the question you are referring to and were very insistent that you meant causing them to *have* or exacerbate the disorder... Understanding is quite a different thing.

Comment: @BryanKrause Learn or Understand. It is an inclusive or. Cause to learn would suffice I think. Maybe the "Or Understand" confused and was redundant. I meant cause young children to learn that disorder by example or experience. And not to understand the disorder. I mainly used the wording from Lexico.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos - That's not what the passage you source means.  It's not indicating that the children merely understand it but indicates that the children acquire the disorder.

Comment: Please make sure questions posted to this site or comprehensible In themselves without the need to visit a third party site which, for all anyone knows, may be booby-trapped with viruses or ad-spam. I therefore vote to close.

Comment: @David agreed. Furthermore, the OP formatted another question on our site similarly, with links providing no context or quotations. Only after lengthy comments and a helpful edit of another member on our site was the question made self-contained. - 1 for seemingly having a disinterest in taking extensive feedback to heart. That said, I do hope the OP edits this question as I do find it interesting.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman And that is precisely what I mean. That they acquire.

Comment: For crying out loud, why did you toss out parts of the suggested edit? Especially your original phrasing! And the reference to my comment won't be around for much longer as I will clean up that thread and simply point here. I'm done trying to help you. You obviously seem to know better. Good luck.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Because my original phrasing is irrelevant to this question. Here I came to get information about the English language in itself and not about my specific question. I was interested in the more general teach + uncommon object and not teach a disorder. To learn one needs to reduce remove the redundant details. It is like trying to solve a system with more variables than linearly independent equations. You will end at best in close forms considering the surplus variables parametres. You cannot find the specific values. One has too many things to explain and too few observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "teach someone something" can have a number of meanings. Where "something" is an area of knowledge, it clearly means to instruct them about that knowledge. If it is a fact like "the earth is round" then it means to inform them of the fact. But if 'something' is an activity or a behaviour or a condition then it can, and normally does, mean to instruct (or cause) them to *do* or *have* that activity or condition.

So if I "teach someone mathematics" then I inform them about mathematics. But if I "teach them football" then I am instructing them on how to *do* football. If I 'teach them crime" then I am showing them how to *do* crime. If I "teach them laziness" then I am causing them to be lazy.

By the same rules **if I "teach someone a disorder" then I am showing them how to *have* that disorder.** It is easy to see how that would be considered wrong.

If you mean that you are giving someone information concerning the disorder, then you should say:

> I am teaching them *about* the disorder.

If you mean you are causing them to have a disorder then you can do this more clearly by saying:

> I am teaching them *to* *have* the disorder.

Comment: Interesting. I was about to up vote this, up to the point where you concluded that that means 'teaching a disorder' would mean 'showing them how to have a disorder'. I guess I don't consider a disorder a behavior or activity... _Is it?_ Furthermore, as you highlight, the main problem with using 'teaching a disorder' is exactly that it seems easily interpreted as incorrect English where the OP actually intended to say 'teaching about a disorder' or even 'teaching somebody that has a disorder'. It is this ambiguity that made the phrasing extremely unclear to two members on our site.

Comment: I much prefer [Benjamin's phrasing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509345/verb-to-teach-while-the-object-that-should-be-taught-is-uncommon#comment1234531_509345) 'teaching to have a disorder' which seems to resolve that ambiguity.

Comment: When I wrote teach a disorder. I meant cause young children to learn or understand that disorder by example or experience.

Comment: Yes, I know you did. But what you actually said doesn't mean that. This answer explains why people didn't understand what you meant, and to show you what phrasing to use so people do understand.

Comment: So it is clear that the meaning is similar to teaching them laziness, teaching them foul language, teaching them bad habits, teaching them table manners. Not teaching them football. I am neither instructing them on how to have a disorder(do football) nor instructing them about disorders(about mathematics). I am causing them the disorder in itself like I would be causing laziness.

Comment: Sorry, but this topic is cracking me up.  Now you totally confused @DJClayworth about what you are actually trying to say by throwing 'to understand' into the mix. So by example, again, no it is _not_ clear.  He believes you are trying to say 'to teach about'.

Comment: Now I'm even confused about whether I'm confused or not.

Comment: By definition that makes you confused, no?  I'm fairly certain he is trying to say 'teach to have a disorder' when saying 'teach a disorder' or even ['learn or understand a disorder'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509345/verb-to-teach-while-the-object-that-should-be-taught-is-uncommon#comment1234552_509345).

Comment: @StevenJeuris When I am saying teach a disorder I mean cause to learn a disorder.

Comment: @DJClayworth When I am saying teach a disorder I mean cause to learn a disorder.

Comment: I've modified the answer to explain how to say unambiguously whichever meaning you want.

Comment: Thank you for the update, @DJClayworth. That improves it. +1 As to your default interpretation of 'teaching a disorder' I am still not fully convinced, though. You don't 'do' a disorder like you do crime. Then again, you also don't 'do' bad language, but you _use_ it though. I think I am missing an equivalent for a disorder for that to make sense. You are diagnosed with a disorder, or possibly you 'have' it. You can exhibit symptoms of a disorder. But these seem different, more indirect, to me.

Comment: @DJClayworth Does teaching them to be lazy have the same connotation as Teaching them laziness? I would think that teaching them to be would be Make (someone) less inclined to do something.
‘I'll teach you to throw rocks at my windows’

Comment: Yes, "teaching them laziness" means the same as "teaching them to be lazy". "I'll teach you to throw rocks at my window." is an idiom that figuratively means the opposite of what it literally means, and is only used in quite specific contexts. It's worth its own question.

Comment: @DJClayworth I mean if it has the same identical connotation(on average between readers), if it stresses, emphasizes and downplays the same things. I am worrying about the nuances and not the greater meaning.

Comment: Yes, "teaching them laziness" means *exactly* the same as "teaching them to be lazy" and has the same connotations. It absolutely does *not* mean the same as 'teaching them *about* laziness.